# HyperV 2016 storage redundancy on non-redundant SANs

Tags: replication, hyper-v-server-2016

We have a setup here consisting of:

1. More or less a dozen of HyperV hosts.
2. Two FC SANS (SAN "A" and SAN "B").

All elements composing this infrastructure are redundant, EXCEPT for the SANs. They are equal in capacity and connected to the HyperV hosts. Unfortunately, storage replication within the SANs is impossible for licensing reasons, and it will take no mor ethan a year (but no less also) to replace them.

What i am trying to achieve is storage replication at HyperV level and within the same cluster.

The idea is, for example, to create LUN "A" on SAN "A" and a new LUN ("B") on SAN "B" and replicate storage from A to B such a sin case of complete failure of one of the SANs the storage on the other takes over, whilst both LUNS are configured within the cluster as Cluster Shared Volumes.

Sadly using the Storage Pools feature does not allow me to replicate the storage, and the Storage Replica feature does not allow me to replicate from LUN A to LUN B as they are on the same site.

Any ideas?. Anyone with a similar scenario?.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel that you need redundant SAN arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using StarWind VSAN (Free) to create a highly available (HA) distributed block device between both Hyper-V hosts on top of an existing SANs attached directly to both servers. Since StarWind talks iSCSI / iSER, you can use it instead of Fibre Channel (FC).

P.S. Good walkthrough is here:

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/synology-diskstation-ds916-turbocharged-with-starwind-virtual-san